# Copy all rows of a pandas Dataframe which have certain bits in column set

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to process a logfile in python. Therefore i read in the logfile and process line for line, create a DataFrame and stored it to a csv-file. In a second step i load this file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path)  # -> load existing file into dataframe
df = df.dropna(subset=['Telegram_Header'])  # -> drop all rows that doesn't have a Telegram Header
df.reset_index()
```

During the processing of the logfile I converted the Telegram_Header entries from 8 byte Hex, e.g. `0C00071A01651118` to `0000110000000000000001110001101000000001011001010001000100011000` this is stored in `df['Telegram_Header]`. Now i want to check for check Header if certain bits are set and copy the complete row of `df` to a new DataFrame `df2`. And this is the point where I'm struggle. What is the best way to do it?

If I loop through every element of `df['Telegram_Header']` i will "find" my entries, but

1. I don't know how to write then the complete row to new DataFrame df2
2. I think this is not a really efficient approach
3. The last two prints doesn't match the previous ones. Here `0000111000000000000001110001101000000001011000011011111100001011` is also printed

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'S': ['I', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M'],
                   'Header': [np.nan, '10101111', '10111011', '10111011', '11001111'],
                   'Data': ['Other Info',
                            'More & longer string with bit pattern',
                            'More & longer string with bit pattern',
                            'More & longer string with bit pattern',
                            'More & longer string with bit pattern']
                   })

df = df.dropna(subset=['Header'])
```

After doing the step I am struggling with I want to have this Result in `df2`

```
   S    Header                                   Data
0  M  10101111  More & longer string with bit pattern
1  M  11001111  More & longer string with bit pattern
```

Any ideas ?

As mentioned above I tried it with

```
for header in df['Header']:
    tmp = int(header, 2) & 15
    if tmp == 15:
        print(header)
```

But i don't know how to copy the complete row of this matching header and i think it is inefficient since the `df` will have a lot of rows.

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example of `df` and the matching expected output for clarity

Comment: @mozway I adjusted it. I hope it is what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your loop with (partially) vectorial code + [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df.loc[(df['Header'].apply(int, args=(2,)) & 15).eq(15)]
```

Output:

```
   S    Header                                   Data
1  M  10101111  More & longer string with bit pattern
4  M  11001111  More & longer string with bit pattern
```

Comment: is it possible to add shifting to that expression? So that i with masking could check for a Sub-Sequenz of  the bit `(num >>4) & 0xFF == 15 `?

Comment: Yes, usint [tag:numpy]: `df2 = df.loc[((df['Header'].apply(int, args=(2,)).to_numpy()>>4) & 0xFF) == 15]`